# Touchpad recognized as a mouse. Touchpad gestures don't work

Tags: touchpad, asus, 16.10, gestures, focaltech

**Laptop:** Asus K501UQ

**OS version:** Ubuntu 16.10

**Kernel:** 4.8.0-26-generic

I am running Ubuntu and I am not able to use touchpad gestures.

My touchpad (i2c-FTE1001:00) is recognized as a mouse, so the gestures (such two fingers scroll, etc.) are not recognized.

Can anyone find a solution to forcing Ubuntu to recognize it as a touchpad with gesture capability?

Error message log:

```
dmesg

[    2.717066] i2c_hid i2c-FTE1001:00: error in i2c_hid_init_report size:633 / ret_size:0
[    2.720630] i2c_hid i2c-FTE1001:00: error in i2c_hid_init_report size:131 / ret_size:0
[    2.720695] input: FTE1001:00 0B05:0101 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-5/i2c-FTE1001:00/0018:0B05:0101.0003/input/input10
[    2.720952] hid-generic 0018:0B05:0101.0003: input,hidraw2: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [FTE1001:00 0B05:0101] on i2c-FTE1001:00
[ 1034.908973] i2c_hid i2c-FTE1001:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (30/1799)
[ 5940.816191] i2c_hid i2c-FTE1001:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (30/256)

xinput list 

↳ FTE1001:00 0B05:0101                      id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

This problem also affects other users, and I am following discussions about it. Here's the [report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=120181).

Comment: If it's a bug, please don't post it here. File a bug in launchpad.

Comment: And where should I post? 
I am asking to be sure, it's a true bug and not my mistake.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 1):

This touchpad is not fully supported by Linux kernel yet.

There is no way to get multitouch working without writing a kernel driver.